# Layer command error in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, layer

I am trying to produce a multi-layer plot in R-Studio using the following syntax:

```
## Load packages
library(foreign)
library(pscl)
library(ggplot2)
library(latticeExtra)
library(DAAG)

## Plot functions and points
fun.1 <- function(x) 1-2*.01*x
fun.2 <- function(x) 1-2*.05*x
fun.3 <- function(x) 1-2*.1*x

puntos <- data.frame(panelp=c(indicator11$propMean, indicator12$propMean , indicator13$propMean,
                            indicator14$propMean, indicator15$propMean), 
                   panelr=c(indicator11$R, indicator12$R, indicator13$R, indicator14$R, indicator15$R),
                   survp=c(indicator21$propMean, indicator22$propMean , indicator23$propMean,
                           indicator24$propMean, indicator25$propMean), 
                   survr=c(indicator21$R, indicator22$R, indicator23$R, indicator24$R, indicator25$R),
                   panelpw=c(indicator11w$propMean, indicator12w$propMean , indicator13w$propMean,
                             indicator14w$propMean, indicator15w$propMean), 
                   panelrw=c(indicator11w$R, indicator12w$R, indicator13w$R, indicator14w$R, indicator15w$R),
                   survpw=c(indicator21w$propMean, indicator22w$propMean , indicator23w$propMean,
                            indicator24w$propMean, indicator25w$propMean), 
                   survrw=c(indicator21w$R, indicator22w$R, indicator23w$R, indicator24w$R, indicator25w$R),
                   modelo=c(1,2,3,4,5))
as.factor(puntos$modelo)


p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0), aes(x = x))

p + 
  layer(stat = "function",
        fun = fun.1, colour="deepskyblue2"
        ) +
  layer(stat = "function",
        fun = fun.2, colour="deepskyblue2"
        ) +
  layer(stat = "function",
        fun = fun.3, colour="deepskyblue2"
        ) +
  geom_point(data=puntos,aes(panelp,panelr, colour=factor(modelo)),size=4) +
  geom_point(data=puntos,aes(survp,survr, colour=factor(modelo)),size=4) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(.0, 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(.6, 1)) +
  ylab("R-indicator") +
  xlab("Response rate") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=1.1, face="bold"))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  ggtitle("R-indicators (unweighted model)") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Models",
                     values = c("chocolate3", "coral1", "darkorchid2", "khaki",
                                "olivedrab4"),
                     labels = c("Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 3", "Model 4", "Model 5"))
```

When running the ggplot2 install I get the following warning (I am using R version 3.3.1)

> Warning message:
>   package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.3.2

After running the above layer command I get the following error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : arguments to layer() should be calls.

I've googled this thinking that the problem lays in the ggplot warning, but most threads say that seeing as it's just a warning and not an error there shouldn't be any problems.

What does argument to layer should be calls actually refer to? Any idea where I might be going wrong (packages installed/commands I use)?

Many thanks!

Comment: You probably should not be using `layer()`, but rather `stat_function()`.

Comment: Also note that `layer` doesn't have `fun` and `colour` arguments.

Comment: Using stat_function() instead of layer() did it! Thank you!